# How to support fast year browsing in jquery UI Datepicker?

Tags: views, datetime, javascript

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker in an exposed filter of a view and I get the following Datepicker:

[image: No direct year browsing]

How is it possible to configure the Datepicker, so that I can quickly navigate through the years, either through a select or through arrows?

Comment: You need to implement something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/odiseo/EuBgE/) using [behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) - original jQuery UI Datepicker does not seem to support fast year selection.

Comment: @Yannis P. can you provide the module link which you are using for Datepciker. I don't understand the datepicker which I'm using supports fast year selection.

Comment: Thank you @Mołot. I haven't done this before so which module's behaviour shall I change the date module, views or a custom one?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan. I am using the date popup from the Date module and then from the admin/config/date/date_popup I chose 'use default jQuery Timepicker'. Then in the view I am using the "Better Exposed Filters" module but I don't think this influences the date

Comment: *"which module's behaviour shall I change"* - none, provide your own module for that :)

Comment: Thank you @Mołot. Anyways I used [Datepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker) and removed "Better Exposed Filters" for this to work. Then in the exposed date filter settings one should choose "Date pop-up" for the datepicker to appear